# Generic way to call Network Requests for API Client

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, client, rx-swift

I have provided the code for my firebase API client.

Is it smart to use generics, to initialize any entity straight from json this way?

To download lists, I needed an indicator to let me know that I'm requesting a list of entities- since there's different implementation, so I added a GETALL  case to my HTTPMethod enum, is this bad, and something that would be confusing to others?

I also feel like this isn't flexible because I can't get desired entities on a node if there are nested at different levels. Hopefully that makes sense. So this probably doesn't follow open/closed principle, because If i have to nest my entities in firebase differently ill have to change implementation inside FirebaseAPI again.

From open source code i've seen, I haven't quite seen an rest client designed like this and not sure if I'm using an anti pattern or something. Any help or guidance to make this maintainable.

```
class FirebaseAPI {

    private let session: URLSession

    init() {

        self.session = URLSession.shared
    }

    /// Responsible for Making actual API requests & Handling response
    /// Returns an observable object that conforms to JSONable protocol.
    /// Entities that confrom to JSONable just means they can be initialized with json.
    func rx_fireRequest<Entity: JSONable>(_ endpoint: Endpoint) -> Observable<[Entity]> {

        return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in

            self?.session.dataTask(with: endpoint.request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                /// Parse response from request.
                let parsedResponse = Parser.init(data: data, response: response, error: error)

                    .parse()


                switch parsedResponse {


                case .error(let error):

                    observer.onError(error)

                    return




                case .success(let data):

                    var entities = [Entity]()

                    /// Consider edge case where a list of entities are retrieved, rather than a single entity.
                    /// Iterate through each entity and initialize.
                    /// Denoted by 'GETALL' method.
                    switch endpoint.method {

                    case .GETALL:


                        /// Key (underscored) is unique identifier for each entity, which is not needed here.
                        /// value is k/v pairs of entity attributes.
                        for (_, value) in data {

                            if let value = value as? [String: AnyObject], let entity = Entity(json: value) {

                                entities.append(entity)

                            } else {

                                observer.onError(NetworkError.initializationFailure)

                                return
                            }

                            observer.onNext(entities)

                            observer.onCompleted()

                            return
                        }



                    default:

                        if let entity = Entity(json: data) {

                        observer.onNext([entity])

                        observer.onCompleted()

                    } else {

                        observer.onError(NetworkError.initializationFailure)

                        }

                    }
                }
            })

            return Disposables.create()
        }


    }
}
```

Enum below Contains all request that can be made to firebase. 
Conforms to Endpoint protocol, so one of these enum members will be the input for FirebaseAPI request method. 
PROBLEM: Seems redundant to have multiple cases for CRUD operations when the only thing that changes is entity involved in the request.

```
enum FirebaseRequest {

    case saveUser(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case findUser(id: String)
    case removeUser(id: String)

    case saveItem(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case findItem(id: String)
    case findItems
    case removeItem(id: String)

    case saveMessage(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case findMessages(chatroomId: String)
    case removeMessage(id: String)

}


extension FirebaseRequest: Endpoint {



    var base: String {

        return ""https://<APPNAME>.firebaseio.com/""
    }

    var path: String {

        switch self {

        case .saveUser(let data): return "\(Constant.users)/\(data[Constant.id])"
        case .findUser(let id): return "\(Constant.users)/\(id)"
        case .removeUser(let id): return "\(Constant.users)/\(id)"

        case .saveItem(let data): return "\(Constant.items)/\(data[Constant.id])"
        case .findItem(let id): return "\(Constant.items)/\(id)"
        case .findItems: return "\(Constant.items)"
        case .removeItem(let id): return "\(Constant.items)/\(id)"

        case .saveMessage(let data): return "\(Constant.messages)/\(data[Constant.id])"
        case .findMessages(let chatroomId): return "\(Constant.messages)/\(chatroomId)"
        case .removeMessage(let id): return "\(Constant.messages)/\(id)"

        /// This is still incomplete... Will have more request.

        }
    }


    var method: Method {

        /// URLRequest method is GET by default, so just consider PUT & DELETE methods.
        switch self {

            /// If saving, return PUT
            /// If removing, return DELETE

        default: return .GET

        }
    }


    var body: [String : AnyObject]? {

        /// If saving, get associated value from enum case, and return that.

        return nil
    }

}
```

Endpoint Protocol

```
protocol Endpoint {

    var base: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var method: Method { get }
    var body: [String: AnyObject]? { get }
    // no params needed for firebase. auth token just goes in url. 
}


extension Endpoint {

    private var urlComponents: URLComponents? {

        var components = URLComponents(string: base)

        components?.path = path + "auth=\(AuthService.shared.authToken)" + ".json"

        return components
    }


    var request: URLRequest {

        var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents!.url!)

        request.httpMethod = self.method.description

        if let body = body {

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])

                request.httpBody = json

            } catch let error {
                // error!
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

        return request
    }

}
```

HTTP Methods

```
enum Method {

    case GET

    /// Indicates how JSON response should be parsed differently to abastract a list of entities
    case GETALL

    case PUT

    case DELETE

}

extension Method: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {

        switch self {

        case .GET: return "GET"
        case .GETALL: return "GET"
        case .PUT: return "PUT"
        case .DELETE: return "DELETE"

        }
    }
}
```

AuthService

```
class AuthService {

    private static let _shared = AuthService()

    static var shared: AuthService {
        return _shared
    }

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    var currentUserId: String {
        return Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    }

    var authToken: AuthCredential {
        return FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
    }


    func rx_login(viewController: UIViewController) {

        /// Facebook login
        rx_facebookLogin(viewController: viewController)

            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (credentials: AuthCredential, userInfo: [String: Any]) in


                /// Firebase Login
                self?.rx_firebaseLogin(with: credentials)

                    .asObservable()
                    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (uid) in

                        /// TODO:  Save in firebase db..





                    }).addDisposableTo((self?.disposeBag)!)

            }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    }




    // - MARK: facebook login
    private func rx_facebookLogin(viewController: UIViewController) -> Observable<(AuthCredential, [String: Any])> {


        return Observable<(AuthCredential, [String: Any])>.create { observable in

            let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

            loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: viewController) { (result, error) in


                guard error == nil else {
                    observable.onError(AuthError.custom(message: error!.localizedDescription))
                    print("debugger: error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                guard let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current() else {
                    observable.onError(AuthError.invalidAccesToken)
                    print("debugger: invalid access token")
                    return
                }


                /// Facebook credentials to login with firebase.
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)


                /// Build request to get user facebook info.
                guard let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: "GET") else {
                    observable.onError(AuthError.facebookGraphRequestFailed)
                    print("debugger: could not create request.")
                    return
                }


                /// - Perform Request
                request.start { (connection, result, error) in

                    guard error == nil else {
                        observable.onError(AuthError.custom(message: error!.localizedDescription))
                        print("debugger: error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }


                    print("Debugger: profile results: \(result)")

                    /// TODO: GET CITY FOR LOCALITY
                    guard let result = result as? [String: AnyObject], let name = result[Constant.name] as? String else {
                        observable.onError(AuthError.invalidProfileData)
                        print("debugger: error converting profile results")
                        return
                    }


                    /// Includes data needed to proceed with firebase login process.
                    observable.onNext((credential, ["name": name]))
                    observable.onCompleted()

                    print("Debugger: Successfull login")
                }

            }

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }




    private func rx_firebaseLogin(with credential: AuthCredential) -> Observable<String> {

        return Observable<String>.create { observable in

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in


                guard error == nil else {
                    observable.onError(AuthError.custom(message: error!.localizedDescription))
                    print("error firelogin \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                guard user != nil else {
                    observable.onError(AuthError.invalidFirebaseUser)
                    print("debugger: error with user..")
                    return
                }

                observable.onNext(user!.uid)
                observable.onCompleted()

            }

            return Disposables.create()

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... why are not you not using the Firebase SDK? It has a database call api with listeners, which works works pretty well

Comment: Honestly it's just because This project is for my portfolio, and thought it would be better to demonstrate an understanding of RESTful API's, rather than firebases sdk which most companies dont use or care about since they prob have their own backend. Doesn't that make sense? But If I was just building this for myself I'd totally use their realtime db with listeners.

Comment: Do you think making up my own method getall to abstract lists of entities means I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would make sense to demonstrate your ability with APIs. To be frank, while i get the idea of generics for network parsing, I think your approach could use some fine tuning for sure. Notably, using a GETALL method like this is self-defeating when you have logic checks which can short-circuit your response. What I mean is you check through an Array, and tell your return object to consider an error as soon as ONE object can't be cast.. On a larger scale say a 1000 object array, is one faulty object really worth not showing the other 999?

Comment: Otherwise, i see the use for generics. I use a standard method and parsing logic class in a custom package, which i then subclass in my projects into more niche class requests with their own types of responses. So what you're trying to achieve (if i correctly assume what your Observable class does), is similar to what i did, minus the class Observable. But yeah, you might have to explain this in an interview.. so i guess it really depends on the employer

Comment: I'd also look at where you check the enpoint.method property. You check it after recieving your reply. I'd check it beforehand, because you might need to make other kinds of URLSession methods for certain kinds of calls. Starting with a basic method which splits that up accordingly would make more sense, and allow you to build on top of that splitting when you add more diversified or use-case specific methods further down the line.

Comment: What I'd do is a method which starts with a switch of enpoint.method before the URLSession, but AFTER you parse the main method's parameters. It then passes on to different network methods for each case, which independently return their specific replies which themselves conform to the global method's return type. Since you want generics, ideally, this way you just need to make sure all of your possible return types conform to the parent's return type. The obvious caveat, just from my reply, is that his can get complex .. especially with conformity.. but in theory, it could be useful.

Comment: Finally (sorry for the spam). The main debate point here for network response generics, would be in cases where conformity is paramount. ie: when recieving a reply from a payment request, when recieving data for a location your app navigates to. Essentially anything which is crucial to the App delivering on its functions or services. Anything else, like the content of a message from a peer (emojis, syntax etc), shouldn't fail its network parsing for a simple interpretation error; that would lead to a lot of frustrated users.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and thorough analysis. At this time, Utilizing the single dataTask method that URLSession offers suffices, for this project. The only time my response handling of a request( whether it be GET, PUT etc) deviates is when I'm retrieving a list of data, which is why thats the only case considered. Also, I don't want to dismiss the 999 objects, so should i simply not emit an error if initialization fails?

Comment: I am going to add a few more classes from my networking layer to give you a better idea of how it comes together. Since I am self- taught, and have never truly gotten any of my code reviewed, I'd really appreciate if you could point out any gaping flaws. your willingness to help this far has lead me to assume you don't mind doing so. Sorry for making that assumption. You've been a great help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150665/discussion-between-murphguy-and-anonprogrammer).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com This is functional code where the user is asking for a review. I was not able to use the "belongs on..." off-topic choice because codereview was not made a choice.