# Rx Observable that gets value from other Observable

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift and MVVM.

my viewModel has a method named `rx_fetchItems(for:)` that does the heavy lifting of fetching relevant content from backend, and returns `Observable<[Item]>`.

My goal is to supply an observable property of the viewModel named `collectionItems`, with the last emitted element returned from `rx_fetchItems(for:)`, to supply my collectionView with data.

Daniel T has provided this solution that I could potentially use:

```
protocol ServerAPI {
    func rx_fetchItems(for category: ItemCategory) -> Observable<[Item]>
}

    struct ViewModel {

        let collectionItems: Observable<[Item]>
        let error: Observable<Error>

        init(controlValue: Observable<Int>, api: ServerAPI) {
            let serverItems = controlValue
                .map { ItemCategory(rawValue: $0) }
                .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! } // or use a `filterNil` operator if you already have one implemented.
                .flatMap { api.rx_fetchItems(for: $0)
                    .materialize()
                }
                .filter { $0.isCompleted == false }
                .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

            collectionItems = serverItems.filter { $0.element != nil }.dematerialize()
            error = serverItems.filter { $0.error != nil }.map { $0.error! }
        }

    }
```

The only problem here is that my current ServerAPI aka FirebaseAPI, has no such protocol method, because it is designed with a single method that fires all requests like this:

```
class FirebaseAPI {

    private let session: URLSession

    init() {
        self.session = URLSession.shared
    }

    /// Responsible for Making actual API requests & Handling response
    /// Returns an observable object that conforms to JSONable protocol.
    /// Entities that confrom to JSONable just means they can be initialized with json.
    func rx_fireRequest<Entity: JSONable>(_ endpoint: FirebaseEndpoint, ofType _: Entity.Type ) -> Observable<[Entity]> {

        return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
            self?.session.dataTask(with: endpoint.request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                /// Parse response from request.
                let parsedResponse = Parser(data: data, response: response, error: error)
                    .parse()

                switch parsedResponse {

                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                    return

                case .success(let data):

                    var entities = [Entity]()

                    switch endpoint.method {

                    /// Flatten JSON strucuture to retrieve a list of entities.
                    /// Denoted by 'GETALL' method.
                    case .GETALL:

                        /// Key (underscored) is unique identifier for each entity, which is not needed here.
                        /// value is k/v pairs of entity attributes.
                        for (_, value) in data {
                            if let value = value as? [String: AnyObject], let entity = Entity(json: value) {
                                entities.append(entity)
                            }
                        }

                        // Need to force downcast for generic type inference.
                        observer.onNext(entities as! [Entity])
                        observer.onCompleted()

                    /// All other methods return JSON that can be used to initialize JSONable entities 
                    default:
                        if let entity = Entity(json: data) {
                        observer.onNext([entity] as! [Entity])
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    } else {
                        observer.onError(NetworkError.initializationFailure)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

The most important thing about the `rx_fireRequest` method is that it takes in  a `FirebaseEndpoint`.

```
/// Conforms to Endpoint protocol in extension, so one of these enum members will be the input for FirebaseAPI's `fireRequest` method.

enum FirebaseEndpoint {

    case saveUser(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case fetchUser(id: String)
    case removeUser(id: String)

    case saveItem(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case fetchItem(id: String)
    case fetchItems
    case removeItem(id: String)

    case saveMessage(data: [String: AnyObject])
    case fetchMessages(chatroomId: String)
    case removeMessage(id: String)

}
```

In order to use Daniel T's solution, Id have to convert each enum case from `FirebaseEndpoint` into methods inside `FirebaseAPI`. And within each method, call `rx_fireRequest`... If I'm correct.

Id be eager to make this change if it makes for a better Server API design. So the simple question is, Will this refactor improve my overall API design and how it interacts with ViewModels. And I realize this is now evolving into a code review.

ALSO... Here is implementation of that protocol method, and its helper:

```
 func rx_fetchItems(for category: ItemCategory) -> Observable<[Item]>  {
        // fetched items returns all items in database as Observable<[Item]>
        let fetchedItems = client.rx_fireRequest(.fetchItems, ofType: Item.self)
        switch category {
        case .Local:
            let localItems = fetchedItems
            .flatMapLatest { [weak self] (itemList) -> Observable<[Item]> in
                return self!.rx_localItems(items: itemList)
            }

            return localItems

            // TODO: Handle other cases like RecentlyAdded, Trending, etc..
        }
    }

    // Helper method to filter items for only local items nearby user.
    private func rx_localItems(items: [Item]) -> Observable<[Item]> {
        return Observable.create { observable in
            observable.onNext(items.filter { $0.location == "LA" })
            observable.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

If my approach to MVVM or RxSwift or API design is wrong PLEASE do critique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that you are only going half-way with the observable paradigm and that's throwing you off. Try taking it all the way and see if that helps. For example:

```
protocol ServerAPI {
    func rx_fetchItems(for category: ItemCategory) -> Observable<[Item]>
}

struct ViewModel {

    let collectionItems: Observable<[Item]>
    let error: Observable<Error>

    init(controlValue: Observable<Int>, api: ServerAPI) {
        let serverItems = controlValue
            .map { ItemCategory(rawValue: $0) }
            .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! } // or use a `filterNil` operator if you already have one implemented.
            .flatMap { api.rx_fetchItems(for: $0)
                .materialize()
            }
            .filter { $0.isCompleted == false }
            .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()

        collectionItems = serverItems.filter { $0.element != nil }.dematerialize()
        error = serverItems.filter { $0.error != nil }.map { $0.error! }
    }
}
```

EDIT to handle problem mentioned in comment. You now need to pass in the object that has the `rx_fetchItems(for:)` method. You should have more than one such object: one that points to the server and one that doesn't point to any server, but instead returns canned data so you can test for any possible response, including errors. (The view model should not talk to the server directly, but should do so through an intermediary...

The secret sauce in the above is the `materialize` operator that wraps error events into a normal event that contains an error object. That way you stop a network error from shutting down the whole system.

---

In response to the changes in your question... You can simply make the FirebaseAPI conform to ServerAPI:

```
extension FirebaseAPI: ServerAPI {
    func rx_fetchItems(for category: ItemCategory) -> Observable<[Item]>  {
        // fetched items returns all items in database as Observable<[Item]>
        let fetchedItems = self.rx_fireRequest(.fetchItems, ofType: Item.self)
        switch category {
        case .Local:
            let localItems = fetchedItems
                .flatMapLatest { [weak self] (itemList) -> Observable<[Item]> in
                    return self!.rx_localItems(items: itemList)
            }

            return localItems

            // TODO: Handle other cases like RecentlyAdded, Trending, etc..
        }
    }

    // Helper method to filter items for only local items nearby user.
    private func rx_localItems(items: [Item]) -> Observable<[Item]> {
        return Observable.create { observable in
            observable.onNext(items.filter { $0.location == "LA" })
            observable.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

You should probably change the name of `ServerAPI` at this point to something like `FetchItemsAPI`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this has been really helpful. I am having trouble getting this to compile though. Where you input category in rx_fetchItems method via flatMap, theres an error that reads "closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter". I think this is because the viewModel is a struct.. But if I change the viewModel to a class, then I get error because Im capturing self in closure before all members are initialized. So it seems I can't have this code in initializer. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe this code could be placed in didSet of property named category? And then I can remove the map and filter operators and start by calling rx_fetchItems in didSet? And the properties collectionItems & error will be optionals.

Comment: My API client actually has code that loads a list of data from the server, and instantiates a model for each item in list from json. Due to the possibility of one initialization failure out of 1000, I chose not to emit error so I can still retrieve the other 999 models that succeeded. It seems that if i use materialize, I can go ahead and emit an error. This is actually discussed in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420616/generic-way-to-call-network-requests-for-api-client?noredirect=1#comment77886469_45420616) of mine you rightfully voted to close.

Comment: You should not be getting "closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter" because self is not being captured in the closure in what I wrote. Placing the code in `didSet` will break the algorithm. You would have to replace the `collectionItems` and `error` every time the value was set which will break all your subscriptions. Rx is declarative, you set it up once in `viewDidLoad` and it works for the life of the view controller. It is an error to continually reset it.

Comment: I think I understand the compile problem. I will adjust the code to suit...

Comment: Your adjustment provides a viable solution if I change my server API design. Would you recommend making the necessary adjustments to utilize your solution in the ViewModel? Please take a look at the original question as I have edited it quite a bit to highlight what changes would need  to be made to use your solution. Thanks for your time Daniel.

Comment: The use of a protocol means you don't have to change the whole design. See my additions above.

Comment: I have this weird bug where the `CollectionView` remains empty until a `segment` is selected. Until then, `collectionItems` remains inactive/cold, even if I change the segment programmatically. It only responds to physical taps. Is this a problem you have come across, or can identify? If you have a moment, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832561/empty-uicollectionview-when-view-loads-with-rxswift/45832719?noredirect=1#comment78662772_45832719) for further details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is tough to start understanding RxSwift

I like to use `Subject`s or `Variable`s as inputs for the **ViewModel** and `Observable`s or `Driver`s as outputs for the **ViewModel**

This way you can bind the actions that happen on the ViewController to the ViewModel, handle the logic there, and update the outputs

Here is an example by refactoring your code

#### View Model

```
// Inputs
let didSelectItemCategory: PublishSubject<ItemCategory> = .init()

// Outputs
let items: Observable<[Item]>

init() {
    let client = FirebaseAPI()

    let fetchedItems = client.rx_fireRequest(.fetchItems, ofType: Item.self)

    self.items = didSelectItemCategory
        .withLatestFrom(fetchedItems, resultSelector: { itemCategory, fetchedItems in
            switch itemCategory {
            case .Local:
                return fetchedItems.filter { $0.location == "Los Angeles" }
            default: return []
            }
        })
}
```

#### ViewController

```
segmentedControl.rx.value
    .map(ItemCategory.init(rawValue:))
    .startWith(.Local)
    .bind(to: viewModel.didSelectItemCategory)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

viewModel.items
    .subscribe(onNext: { items in
        // Do something
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: IMHO, this is not an appropriate use of Subjects in the long run, but it can get you past the learning curve... http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DanielT., but do you think it is a problem if you don't manually trigger events on the subject? In this case, it is only being used to bind the action to the vm...

Comment: In this particular case, the `segmentedControl.rx.value` already is an observable, so you don't need the `PublishSubject`. Just pass the observable into the view model and bind it directly instead of using the subject as an intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

You run into a tricky situation here because your observable can throw an error and once it does throw an error the observable sequence errors out and no more events can be emitted. So to handle subsequent network requests, you must reassign taking the approach you're currently taking. However, this is generally not good for driving UI elements such as a collection view because you would have to bind to the reassigned observable every time. When driving UI elements, you should lean towards types that are guaranteed to not error out (i.e. Variable and Driver). You could make your `Observable<[Item]>` to be `let items = Variable<[Item]>([])` and then you could just set the value on that variable to be the array of items that came in from the new network request. You can safely bind this variable to your collection view using RxDataSources or something like that. Then you could make a separate variable for the error message, let's say `let errorMessage = Variable<String?>(nil)`, for the error message that comes from the network request and then you could bind the errorMessage string to a label or something like that to display your error message.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! And am I assigning my items observable variable to results of fetched items in the right place (subscribing in didset).  In viewcontroller, when I subscribe to items property Nothing gets printed out in onNext block.